# I'm trying to transform this SQL to Eloquent so I can filter with it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm a student and I'm trying to make a filter for my products. I have a pretty big SQL query which I'm trying to put in eloquent so I can filter using it. This is the SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (

    SELECT p.id, p.name AS 'nombre_producto', sc.category_id AS 'id_categoria', p.status AS status, p.price AS precio, p.subcategory_id AS subcategoria, b.name AS nombre_marca, SUM(cs.quantity) AS cantidad_color, sc.color AS color, sc.size AS talla, p.created_at, p.updated_at
    FROM products AS p
    INNER JOIN subcategories AS sc ON p.subcategory_id = sc.id
    INNER JOIN sizes AS sz ON sz.product_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN color_size AS cs ON cs.size_id = sz.id
    INNER JOIN brands AS b ON b.id = p.brand_id
    WHERE (sc.color = 1 AND sc.size = 1)
    GROUP BY p.name, sc.category_id, p.status, p.price, p.subcategory_id, b.name, sc.color, sc.size, p.created_at, p.updated_at

    UNION

    SELECT p.id, p.name AS 'nombre_producto', sc.category_id AS 'id_categoria', p.status AS status, p.price AS precio, p.subcategory_id AS subcategoria, b.name AS nombre_marca, SUM(cp.quantity) AS stock, sc.color AS color, sc.size AS talla, p.created_at, p.updated_at
    FROM products AS p
    INNER JOIN subcategories AS sc ON p.subcategory_id = sc.id
    INNER JOIN color_product AS cp ON cp.product_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN brands AS b ON b.id = p.brand_id
    WHERE (sc.size = 0 AND sc.color = 1)
    GROUP BY p.name, sc.category_id, p.status, p.price, p.subcategory_id, b.name, sc.color, sc.size , p.created_at, p.updated_at

    UNION

    SELECT p.id, p.name AS 'nombre_producto', sc.category_id AS 'id_categoria', p.status AS status, p.price AS precio, p.subcategory_id AS subcategoria, b.name AS nombre_marca, p.quantity AS stock, sc.color AS color, sc.size AS talla, p.created_at, p.updated_at
    FROM products as p
    INNER JOIN subcategories AS sc ON p.subcategory_id = sc.id
    INNER JOIN brands AS b ON b.id = p.brand_id
    WHERE (sc.size = 0 AND sc.color = 0)

) AS catalogo
ORDER BY catalogo.id;
```

The problem comes when I try to make the SELECT to all of this, this is the progress I made up this far

```
$pTalla = Product::select('products.name as nombre_producto', 'subcategories.category_id as id_categoria', 'products.status as status', 'products.price as precio', 'products.subcategory_id as subcategoria', 'brands.name as nombre_marca', DB::raw("SUM('color_size.quantity') as cantidad_color"), 'subcategories.color as color', 'subcategories.size as talla', 'products.created_at', 'products.updated_at')
            ->join('subcategories','products.subcategory_id','=','subcategories.id')
            ->join('sizes','sizes.product_id','=','products.id')
            ->join('color_size','color_size.size_id','=','sizes.id')
            ->join('brands','brands.id','=','products.brand_id')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where([['subcategories.color','=',1], ['subcategories.size','=',1]]);
            })
            ->groupByRaw('products.name, subcategories.category_id, products.status, products.price, products.subcategory_id, brands.name, subcategories.color, subcategories.size, products.created_at, products.updated_at')
            ->get();

$pColor = Product::select('products.name as nombre_producto', 'subcategories.category_id as id_categoria', 'products.status as status', 'products.price as precio', 'products.subcategory_id as subcategoria', 'brands.name as nombre_marca', DB::raw("SUM('color_product.quantity') as stock"), 'subcategories.color as color', 'subcategories.size as talla', 'products.created_at', 'products.updated_at')
            ->join('subcategories','products.subcategory_id','=','subcategories.id')
            ->join('color_product','color_product.product_id','=','products.id')
            ->join('brands','brands.id','=','products.brand_id')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where([['subcategories.color','=',1], ['subcategories.size','=',0]]);
            })
            ->groupByRaw('products.name, subcategories.category_id, products.status, products.price, products.subcategory_id, brands.name, subcategories.color, subcategories.size, products.created_at, products.updated_at')
            ->get();

$pColor->union($pTalla);

$pNormales = Product::select('products.name as nombre_producto', 'subcategories.category_id as id_categoria', 'products.status as status', 'products.price as precio', 'products.subcategory_id as subcategoria', 'brands.name as nombre_marca', 'products.quantity as stock', 'subcategories.color as color', 'subcategories.size as talla', 'products.created_at', 'products.updated_at')
            ->join('subcategories','products.subcategory_id','=','subcategories.id')
            ->join('brands','brands.id','=','products.brand_id')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where([['subcategories.color','=',0], ['subcategories.size','=',0]]);
            })
            ->get();

$pNormales->union($pColor);
```

This query is going to be used in a class to make filters for products like by brand, by price, etc.

Comment: So what's the actual question? You've explain what you're trying to do, and have shown the code you've written, but I don't see a question here. Is something broken? What is not working? What is your expected outcome vs your actual outcome?

Comment: My question is  how can i put the three variables ( $pTalla, $pColor, $pNormales)  in the same variable, for example $result, so I can make my filters with it, in mysql is the SELECT * from the three other selct, but i dont know how to do it in eloquent.

Comment: Did you try `$result = $pNormales->union($pColor)->get();`? `->get()` will execute the query, but you can chain as many calls before that as needed.

Comment: I tried but it throw the next error: `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0` but if i use $pNormales it shows me data

Comment: Ah, cause you're calling `->get()` in a couple other spots. Remove those `->get()` calls before your `->union()` calls, and then my suggestion should work.

Comment: It worked, now i have this `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union`

Comment: You'll have to check the generated SQL by calling `->toSql()` instead of `->get()`, and debug why that is the case.

Comment: Okay, i tried that and I need tod do a `SELECT *  FROM $pNormales->union($pColor)->get()`, is there any way to do it with eloquent?

Comment: Ah, cause you wrap the `union`s with a `SELECT * FROM (...)`. Maybe `DB::select()->from($pNormales->union($pColor))->get()`? I haven't done one of these queries before unfortunately.

Comment: I tried but with no success and i dont know how to do it, but thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Keep looking through the documentation, and search Google/Stackoverflow for similar questions, like "Nested Select Laravel", or similar keywords; chances are you're not the first to have this issue 

Comment: @Tim Lewis That's almost it. The syntax should be `DB::query()->from($query, 'alias')->get();` (`fromSub(query, alias)` should be equivalent as well) . `DB::select()` does not use the query builder and expects raw sql. Another (shorter) syntax is `DB::table($query, 'alias')->get()`.  (`DB::table(...)` basically calls `DB::query()->from(...)` ). I've gone in detail in the answer below

Comment: @IGP Good stuff! I thought `DB::select()` was the builder and `DB::statement()` was the raw query one (considering there's a `selectRaw()` method too), but yeah, after testing you are correct! Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Comment: `DB::statement()` does not return any usable value. The only way I've seen it used is to set sql variables or run raw `CREATE/ALTER TABLE/INDEX`

Answer (score 1):

You should end up with something like this.

```php
$results = DB::query()
    ->fromSub($query, 'catalogo')
    ->orderBy('catalogo.id')
```

This will generate the following query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ( .... ) AS catalogo
ORDER BY catalogo.id ASC
```

---

`$query` should be either a `Closure` or a `Builder` object. I'm going to use `Builder` because it's easier to show.

Your query has some unions. You should think of it like this:

```sql
--start of subquery 1
SELECT ....
--end of subquery 1
UNION
--start of subquery 2
SELECT ...
--end of subquery 2
UNION
--start of subquery 3
SELECT ...
--end of subquery 3
```

Using Laravel's Query Builder, you need to use the `union($query)` method to write `UNION`s. Just like before, `$query` can be either a `Closure` or a `Builder`.

It's as easy as chaining them.

```php
$subquery_1->union($subquery_2)->union($subquery_3);
```

---

`$subquery_1`, `$subquery_2` and `$subquery_3` are all `Builder` instances in this example.

Taking all of this into account, your query can be written as follows:

```php
$subquery_1 = Product::query()
    ->select('products.name as nombre_producto', 'subcategories.category_id as id_categoria', 'products.status as status', 'products.price as precio', 'products.subcategory_id as subcategoria', 'brands.name as nombre_marca', DB::raw("SUM('color_size.quantity') as cantidad_color"), 'subcategories.color as color', 'subcategories.size as talla', 'products.created_at', 'products.updated_at')
    ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
    ->join('sizes', 'sizes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('color_size', 'color_size.size_id', '=', 'sizes.id')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where([
            ['subcategories.color', '=', 1],
            ['subcategories.size', '=', 1]
        ]);
    })
    ->groupByRaw('products.name, subcategories.category_id, products.status, products.price, products.subcategory_id, brands.name, subcategories.color, subcategories.size, products.created_at, products.updated_at');

$subquery_2 = Product::query()
    ->select('products.name as nombre_producto', 'subcategories.category_id as id_categoria', 'products.status as status', 'products.price as precio', 'products.subcategory_id as subcategoria', 'brands.name as nombre_marca', DB::raw("SUM('color_product.quantity') as stock"), 'subcategories.color as color', 'subcategories.size as talla', 'products.created_at', 'products.updated_at')
    ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
    ->join('color_product', 'color_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where([
            ['subcategories.color', '=', 1],
            ['subcategories.size', '=', 0]
        ]);
    })
    ->groupByRaw('products.name, subcategories.category_id, products.status, products.price, products.subcategory_id, brands.name, subcategories.color, subcategories.size, products.created_at, products.updated_at');

$subquery_3 = Product::query()
    ->select('products.name as nombre_producto', 'subcategories.category_id as id_categoria', 'products.status as status', 'products.price as precio', 'products.subcategory_id as subcategoria', 'brands.name as nombre_marca', 'products.quantity as stock', 'subcategories.color as color', 'subcategories.size as talla', 'products.created_at', 'products.updated_at')
    ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where([
            ['subcategories.color', '=', 0],
            ['subcategories.size', '=', 0]
        ]);
    });

$query = $subquery_1->union($subquery_2)->union($subquery_3);

$results = DB::query()->fromSub($query, 'catalogo')->orderBy('catalogo.id')->get();
```